# I need an IF formula to CHOOSE between two cells. If the first cell has an output of FALSE, then choose the other cell that has a numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Incorrect formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvNn7.jpg)
I've got two cells that will alternate their answer based on a selection on a different sheet. However, I need a single cell to represent the answer that has a numerical value. If the single cell sees the text as "FALSE" then it will look at the other one that is showing a numerical value.

Answer (score 3):

Providing you can ensure that one of the cells always contains FALSE whilst the other contains a numeric value, a simple test of a single cell with an IF statement should suffice:

=IF(AS68=FALSE(),AS73,AS68)

or

=IF(ISNUMBER(AS68),AS68,AS73)

Of course, this could be extended with a test for the untested cell, producing an error if the cell value is not a numeric value.

Comment: I would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you!

Comment: @AddisonHimes Please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).